# Coldfusion CFML Howto share DB Results between subpages

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, lucee, railo, cfquery

I have a big DB Query (cfquery with many columns and rows) where the result has to be shared between two sub-webpages for scrolling all the entries back and forth. Calling the db query after switching between the pages is no options since it will be very laggy, therefore I try to avoid it.

Since this question seems to be trivial, I am not capable of finding a solution. Is there a best way/practice for this kind of issue?

I have tried to but the result into a struct but still no idea how to pass this "variable" to another page.

Comment: Depends on how big "big" is. You could use the `cachedwithin` attribute within `cfquery` to store the resultset in memory.

Comment: You could also, again depending on size, store into a session variable.  The cachedwithin that @TRose suggests is probably better, especially if re-used by multiple users.  If you plan to change the underlying data, though, you will have to make sure you're next retrieval does NOT used the cachedwithin argument, to ensure you get fresh db data.

Comment: Where is the lag/delay?  Is it querying the DB or the actual display of data to the screen?

Comment: Show some code!

Comment: Yup, show the code, give some idea of the nature of the data (session-specific, request-specific, same for everyone in the application?), quantify what "big" is, and why it needs to be "big", how it's being used etc. And is it *really* a Railo question? Or is it Lucee? Or CF? Probs only need the most accurate one of those tags. Also poss explain what you mean by "sub webpage". Do you mean "two separate requests"? I suspect @TRose is on the right track with `cachedwithin`, but it really depends on all the questions I ask before being able to give a good answer.